Using "get it" in the sense of " deal with it"?
"The floor is dirty.can somebody sweep it?"
"No problem,I'll get it/I'll deal with it"
Does "I'll get it" have the same meaning as "I'll deal with it"?

There's little more to be said than yes, they mean the same thing. I speculate that "I'll get" it is a contraction of "I'll get on with it" or even "I'll get on with doing that task"
According to Google Ngrams the phrase has been in use since the late 1600s with a slow rise between 1850 and 2000 followed by a rapid one since. "I'll deal with it" has seen virtually no usage up until 2000 when it has grown somewhat, but still only one eighth of "I'll get it".

or I'll get it sorted, or I'll get [that problem] out of the way. The possibilities are endless. You hear the doorbell or the phone, you say I'll get that.
